# Why do I get this error: "could not convert string to float: '.' "?Why doesn't it work with numbers bigger than 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I was trying to create a program that takes a sequence of decimal numbers separated by commas and prints their sum, but it gives me this error:

could not convert string to float: '.'

and the code doesn't work with numbers bigger than 10, may anyone help me please?
This is my code:

```
s = "1.1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
v = 0
r = 0
for i in s:
    if i != ",":
        v+= float(i)
    else:
        v = 0

    r += v
print(r)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to convert each *character*? Surely you want to convert each *number* represented in that string, i.e. iterate over `s.split(',')`? This approach inevitably cannot work with any number that contains more than a single digit, whether that's `11` (which just becomes `2`) or `1.1` (which errors as above). Your logic is off for all but the most trivial cases.

Comment: why `r+=v` can you explain??

Answer (score 2):

Because in your loop `.` is also a character which can't be converted.

Just corrected you syntax wise:

```
s = "1.1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
v = 0
r = 0
for i in s.split(','):
    if i != ",":
        v+= float(i)
    else:
        v = 0

    r += v
print(r)
```

Sum for decimal numbers code

```
s = "1.1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
v = 0
for i in s.split(','):
        v+= float(i)
print(v)
```

Or

```
s = "1.1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
print(sum(map(float,s.split(','))))
```

Comment: How could `i != ","` ever evaluate to `False` now? Also note that you haven't made a *syntax* change, but a *logical* one; the OP's code was syntactically valid but not meaningful.

Comment: yeah i know thats why i said i corrected syntax wise

Comment: That's not what that means.